# Using SkPhysicsBody contact

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Below is my code that is part of a game, right now there are a few things that are going wrong when the game is played. The first is that the bullets shoot out of the bottom side of the physics shape for the hero instead of out of the center of the shape. The other is that the collision detection between the hero and enemy doesn't always work and makes the hero ship do random things. What part of the category bit mask and contact bit do I have wrong for these?

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

class hero: SKSpriteNode {
    var width: CGFloat = 0.0
    var height: CGFloat = 0.0

    func createShip() {

        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)

        self.zPosition = 1.0
        self.physicsBody?.mass = 0.02
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionHeroCategory.rawValue
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ObjectCategory.sceneCategory.rawValue | ObjectCategory.collisionEnemyCategory.rawValue
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ObjectCategory.sceneCategory.rawValue | ObjectCategory.collisionEnemyCategory.rawValue
        self.position = CGPointMake(width, height)

    }
}

class enemy:SKSpriteNode {

    func createEnemyShip(heroShipSize:CGSize,viewFrame:CGRect) -> SKSpriteNode{
        let enemyShip = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyShip")
        enemyShip.position = CGPointMake(viewFrame.maxX + enemyShip.size.height, CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(viewFrame.maxY) - UInt32(enemyShip.size.width))))
        enemyShip.name = "enemyShip"
        enemyShip.zPosition = 1.0
        enemyShip.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        enemyShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: heroShipSize)
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.mass = 5
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionEnemyCategory.rawValue
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionBulletCategory.rawValue | ObjectCategory.collisionHeroCategory.rawValue
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionBulletCategory.rawValue | ObjectCategory.collisionHeroCategory.rawValue
        return enemyShip
    }
}

class bullet:SKSpriteNode{
    func createBullet(heroShipPosition:CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode{
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
        bullet.position = CGPointMake(heroShipPosition.x, heroShipPosition.y)
        bullet.zPosition = 1.0
        // Add physics body for collision detection
        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet.frame.size)
        bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionBulletCategory.rawValue
        bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionEnemyCategory.rawValue
        bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionEnemyCategory.rawValue
        return bullet
    }
}

enum ObjectCategory:UInt32{
    case collisionBulletCategory  =  0
    case collisionHeroCategory =  1
    case sceneCategory =  2
    case collisionEnemyCategory =  3

}
```

Below is the contact function in my scene

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ObjectCategory.collisionBulletCategory.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ObjectCategory.collisionEnemyCategory.rawValue{
    score++
    }

    if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ObjectCategory.collisionEnemyCategory.rawValue && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ObjectCategory.collisionHeroCategory.rawValue{
        endGame()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you had read my answer on your other post,  I already answered your problem with the physics body contact

Comment: it is shooting the bullets out of the bottom of the physics body and shooting them from the center of my ship, I want them to shoot out the tip

Comment: your bullets are firing out of your anchor point,  is this the tip of your ship?

Comment: you deleted this post while I was answering some other issues you have,  so I had to comment the old question. This is a duplicate comment to answer some issues: Your other issues are bodyA is never guaranteed to be bullet, so you need to account for both cases where bodyA is bullet and bodyB is bullet,  and your categories need to be in a power of 2,  these are bit mask flags, so 3 actually means sceneCategory and collissionHero, because in binary, 3 is 0011 (Thus 2 categories),  but you need to make it 0100 in binary to give it a unique category

Comment: This is on the enum?

Comment: the enum needs to be 1 2 4 8 16 etc

Comment: ahh that makes sense, that fixed it